# Open URL in Browser Cordova Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have been trying to get inAppBrowser to load my url in an external browser on Android. I have set up inAppBrowser, however using _blank or _system leads to the same outcome. The webpage loads inside the app instead of going out to a browser.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="external" id="link-forgotPass" >Forgot Password?</a>
```

JS:

```
$('#link-forgotPass').bind('click', app.goToForgotPass);
goToForgotPass: function() {
    window.open('www.google.com', '_system', 'location=no');
    return false;
}
```

XML:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

What am I missing? Do I need to bind inAppBrowser some how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add google.com to the Whitelist? Do you get any errors in logcat?

Comment: how do i add to whitelist? No errors it just loads the url within the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to use InAppBrowser plugin with no avail I found the following snippet. This seems to work in Android for Cordova 3.3. (I chose to bind the `<a>` element to a click event in order to execute the javascript code)

Javascript:

```
 $('#link-forgotPass').bind('click', function() { navigator.app.loadUrl('your.url.here', {openExternal:true}); });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="external" id="link-forgotPass" >Forgot Password?</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Cordova do you have? If it's >= 3.0 you can install the [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md) plugin.

And if its lower, the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) says that you have to add:

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```

in `app/res/xml/config.xml`

Comment: it is 3.3 and I have installed the inAppBrowser plugin. It does not work